# Error when running pocketsphinx_continuous: Acoustic model definition is not specified

Tags: cmusphinx, linux-mint, pocketsphinx

When I run `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes`, I get this error: `ERROR: "acmod.c", line 85: Acoustic model definition is not specified neither with -mdef option nor with -hmm`.

I've already read the information in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132192/pocketsphinx-continuous-failed-to-open-audio-device) as well as the [Pocketsphinx FAQ](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qfailed_to_open_audio_device_dev_dsp_no_such_file_or_directory), and neither of those helped.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
pocketsphinx_continuous \
    -inmic yes 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-adcdev             
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-argfile            
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   yes     yes
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                
-infile             
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      -1
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      -1
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-time       no      no
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 85: Acoustic model definition is not specified neither with -mdef option nor with -hmm
```

I'm building an app using the [pocketsphinx-ruby gem](https://github.com/watsonbox/pocketsphinx-ruby). I've already installed it on OS X successfully, but now I'm trying to install it on my home computer running Linux Mint 17. I at first compiled it from source, but I wound up having issues with it not recognizing my audio libraries, so I instead opted for the version in the Synaptic Package Manager.

I already have the libpulse-dev and libasound2 packages installed.

So, thoughts? How should I solve this issue? Am I missing any packages? Should I try from source again?

Answer (score 5):

it is because a package is not installed by default, try 
    `sudo apt-get install pocketsphinx-hmm-en-hub4wsj` (from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/980263ec/) and [here](http://wisercoder.com/common-pocketsphinx-mistakes-fix/))

Comment: In recent ubuntu the package name is pocketsphinx-en-us.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is for Linux. For Windows, after downloading pocketsphinx, construct the command like this from within the "bin\Release\Win32" folder (you will need to paste the custom keywords file "keywordfile.gram" that you are wanting to test, as well as your sample.wav, into the bin folder to avoid having to specify a long path):

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile sample.wav -kws keywordfile.gram -dict "[path-to-pocketphinx-folder]\model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict" -hmm "[path-to-pocketphinx-folder]\model\en-us\en-us"
```

I almost gave up hope until I figured this out! Documentation is sorely lacking.

Comment: This is not something worth downvoting IMO. I know the original question had OSX, but it's nice to see a solution that works for Windows too. It helped me :)