# Failing to open audio device (/dev/dsp)

Tags: c, linux, cmusphinx, pulseaudio, ubuntu-17.04

I am using pocketsphinx to adapt my acoustic model which i have trained.

So to use the model in pocketsphinx, i ran the following command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -lm "/home/ridwan/sphinx/other/output/other.lm.DMP" -dict "/home/ridwan/sphinx/other/output/other.dic" -hmm "/home/ridwan/sphinx/other/output/other.ci_cont"
```

But however, I am getting this error:

```
ad_oss.c(115): Failed to open audio device(/dev/dsp): Input/output error
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device
```

I tried this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28189990/13419834) (installing pulseaudio, libpulse-dev, osspd)

I also tried `export LD_PRELOAD=libpulsedsp.so`

But I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: To list known playback devices: `aplay -l` To list capture devices `arecord -l`

Comment: @stark, this does not solve the issue, rather it just gives a list of playback/capture devices.

Comment: Comments are not intended to be answers. Had you thought to add the output to the question, then perhaps someone could help you.  /dev/dsp is a relic of the OSS audio system no longer used by Linux.